# Necessary regularity conditions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I consider the following function $f$:
$$
\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R},\quad f(x,y)=\min \{t\in \mathbb{R}^+\; \mathrm{s.t.}\; 2tx\geq y^2\}
$$
which essentially defines the equation of a rotating quadratic cone. Formally, I then define the following function:

\begin{equation}
E(u) = \int_{0}^1 f(u(x),u'(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

My question concerns what regularity is necessary for $u$ in order for $E(u)$ to make sense. If $u(x)\neq 0$, it seems to me that we can write:

$$
f(u(x),u'(x)) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{u'(x)^2}{u(x)} = 2\left(\sqrt{u(x)}'\right)^2
$$
Could this be helpful?

THANKS.

Comment: Huh? $f(x,y) = {1 \over 2} x y^2$, so $f(u(x),u'(x)) = {1 \over 2} u(x) (u'(x))^2$.

Comment: Sorry of my mistake in the first equation, we have $f(x,y)=y^2/(2x)$ is $x\neq 0$.